# React native How to fetch from api every x minutes

Tags: android, react-native

I want to run fetch every x Minutes on android (using React native)

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() { 
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json').then((response) => response.json()) .then((responseJson) => { 
  return responseJson.movies; }) .catch((error) => { console.error(error); }); 
}
```

I went to use example from documentaion as i am not still sure how would i do this kind of fetch.

Im not sure on how should i even start this(Make a android native Handler maybe?). I only found a component but that is for ios [iOS Background Fetch API Implementation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
 componentDidMount(){
  this.timer = setInterval(()=> this.getMovies(), 1000)
 }

async getMovies(){

 fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', {method: "GET"})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) =>
  {
    //set your data here
     console.log(responseData);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
  });

}
```

Comment: App is crashing after 20-30 seconds

Comment: I asked this question for a firend who was blocked with this issue,he managed to solved it just an hour ago.Thank you very much for responding.

Comment: this is not the solution. it will wait until the first fetch finish

Comment: I think I have a way for making sure the last fetch has finished. See my answer below. Hope it helps

Comment: For this to work properly you need to use `async` `await` or any other asynchronous method  `this.timer = setInterval(async()=> await this.getMovies(), 1000)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want run your service in background then there is only one option you have that is headless js  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html or npm based on headless js like https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

headless base service can have minimum periodic frequency 15 not less than that

if need to run service lesser than that eg 5 minutes then you can use combination of headless js and setinterval like

```
   BackgroundTask.define(async () => { //headless based runs every 15 minute
        console.log('headless js service start')

         this._interval = setInterval(() => {
         console.log('setinterval for 5 minute start')
        // Your code
         }, 300000);

          BackgroundTask.finish()
     })
```

then inside your any component method like componentwillmount you need to schedule background task like

```
 componentDidMount() {
      BackgroundTask.schedule({
      period: 900, // Aim to run every 15mins 
      })
      }
```

you can use setinterval alone without headless JS but will be stop by android to save battery/resource

Note : to test these things you have to use real device as physical device go in doze mode or do things like stop background app to save battery/resource unlike emulators

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the party but I had to do something similar. I was making an API request to a server that fetches a bunch of locations, does some calculations and passes the data to a callback function in another part of the app to update a Map. I wanted this to run every "x" seconds. This is what I did:

I created a custom hook that I call from the map screen. I had two states I wanted to return (businessLocations, error). I created a timer at the top of the file that looks like this:

```
const [render, setRender] = useState(false);
 
useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      setRender(!render);
   }, 20000);
}, [isScreenFocused, render]);
```

This was recreated every time the screen was focused or the render state changed. As you can see I trigger the render state to change every time 20 seconds is up causing the timer to re-start.

Below the `useEffect` call I created a second `useEffect` call that looks like this:

```
const fetching = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {

        const searchForLocations = async () => {

            fetching.current = true;

            await requestAllLocations()
                .then((locations) => {

                    const results = locations.map(loc => {
                        return createBusinessFromAPI(loc);
                    });

                    setBusinessLocations(results);
                    locationsCallback(results);

                    fetching.current = false;

                }).catch((error) => {
                    fetching.current = false;
                    throw error;
                });
        };

        if (!fetching.current) {
            searchForLocations().catch(error => setError(error));
        }

    }, [isScreenFocused, render]);
```

As you can see here, I use the hook `useRef` (which doesn't change from render to render) to determine if the last request is still processing. If it is, I don't call `searchForLocations()` on this render cycle and simply wait for the next one. You can also see that this entire `useEffect` call is triggered when the timer is up because I use the render state as a dependency here too.

It may not be a perfect solution. I'm currently trying to refine it a little. But, it has worked for me so far.

Here is the entire file:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {requestAllLocations} from '../api/requests';
import {createBusinessFromAPI} from '../model/BusinessCreator';

export default (isScreenFocused, locationsCallback) => {

    const [businessLocations, setBusinessLocations] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [render, setRender] = useState(false);

    const fetching = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setRender(!render);
        }, 20000);
    }, [isScreenFocused, render]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const searchForLocations = async () => {

            fetching.current = true;

            await requestAllLocations()
                .then((locations) => {

                    const results = locations.map(loc => {
                        return createBusinessFromAPI(loc);
                    });

                    setBusinessLocations(results);
                    locationsCallback(results);

                    fetching.current = false;

                }).catch((error) => {
                    fetching.current = false;
                    throw error;
                });
        };

        if (!fetching.current) {
            searchForLocations().catch(error => setError(error));
        }

    }, [isScreenFocused, render]);

    return [businessLocations, error];
};
```

Comment: I had success using this approach. Only thing to note is that you need to check that the component is mounted before `setRender` is called in the first `useEffect`. I was running into issues where I would get no-ops because the timeout function would be scheduled to run after my component already unmounted. I fixed it by using the method outlined in [this article](https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the time on that place where you get callback .

```
ComponentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((token) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
         time :5000

      });
    });
  },
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But how would i run a timer in the background? Does react native has something like that. Or must i make a android native method

Comment: I think you have to load data at a single time from api and just display according your business need.

Comment: Why im asking this is that i need to check changes every X minutes. So if lets say one value is greater than other in these intervals. A message would appear on users screen.

Answer (score -7):

You can make a AsyncTask(background thread) where it gets the json from your url and call it in a Timer loop like so:

Asynctask:

```
private class FetchAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    BufferedReader reader;
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = null;
        try {
            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL(YOURURL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();

            // Get the server response
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            // conn.disconnect();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            String serverResponse = sb.toString(); //Your JSON

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Your timer segment:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // do your task here
    FetchAPI fetchAPI = new FetchAPI();
    fetchAPI.execute("");
}
}, 0, 5000);
```

This code will call the FetchAPI method which uses the background thread to fetch the json from your URL. When you've gotten the JSON you can do what you want with it. The method gets called every 5 seconds. Edit the '5000'(interval in miliseconds) to your needs

I hope this can help you and/or steer you in the right direction

Comment: I think it will now i just how to figure out how React native calls native functions and try to make this work. Thank your for the code